# Bit-shifting audio samples from Float32 to SInt16 results in severe clipping

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, core-audio, audiounit

I'm new to the iOS and its C underpinnings, but not to programming in general. My dilemma is this. I'm implementing an echo effect in a complex AudioUnits based application. The application  needs reverb, echo, and compression, among other things. However, the echo only works right when I use a particular **AudioStreamBasicDescription** format for the audio samples generated in my app. This format however doesn't work with the other AudioUnits. 
While there are other ways to solve this problem fixing the bit-twiddling in the echo algorithm might be the most straight forward approach.

The**AudioStreamBasicDescription** that works with echo has a **mFormatFlag** of:  *kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical*; It's specifics are:

```
AudioUnit Stream Format (ECHO works, NO AUDIO UNITS)
Sample Rate:              44100
Format ID:                 lpcm
Format Flags:              3116 = kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical
Bytes per Packet:             4
Frames per Packet:            1
Bytes per Frame:              4
Channels per Frame:           2
Bits per Channel:            32
Set ASBD on input
Set ASBD on  output
au SampleRate rate: 0.000000, 2 channels, 12 formatflags, 1819304813 mFormatID, 16 bits per channel
```

The stream format that works with AudioUnits is the same except for the **mFormatFlag**: *kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved* -- Its specifics are:

```
AudioUnit Stream Format (NO ECHO, AUDIO UNITS WORK)
Sample Rate:              44100
Format ID:                 lpcm
Format Flags:                41 
Bytes per Packet:             4
Frames per Packet:            1
Bytes per Frame:              4
Channels per Frame:           2
Bits per Channel:            32
Set ASBD on input
Set ASBD on  output
au SampleRate rate: 44100.000000, 2 channels, 41 formatflags, 1819304813 mFormatID, 32 bits per channel
```

In order to create the echo effect I use two functions that bit-shift sample data into **SInt16** space, and back. As I said, this works for the *kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical*, format but not the other. When it fails, the sounds are clipped and distorted, but they are there. I think this indicates that the difference between these two formats is how the data is arranged in the **Float32**.

```
// convert sample vector from fixed point 8.24 to SInt16
void fixedPointToSInt16( SInt32 * source, SInt16 * target, int length ) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < length; i++ ) {
        target[i] =  (SInt16) (source[i] >> 9);
        //target[i] *= 0.003;

    }
}
```

*As you can see I tried modifying the amplitude of the samples to get rid of the clipping -- clearly that didn't work.

```
// convert sample vector from SInt16 to fixed point 8.24 
void SInt16ToFixedPoint( SInt16 * source, SInt32 * target, int length ) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < length; i++ ) {
        target[i] =  (SInt32) (source[i] << 9);
        if(source[i] < 0) { 
            target[i] |= 0xFF000000;
        }
        else {
            target[i] &= 0x00FFFFFF;
        }
    }
}
```

If I can determine the difference between *kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved*, then I can modify the above methods accordingly. But I'm not sure how to figure that out. Documentation in CoreAudio is enigmatic, but from what I've read there, and gleaned from the **CoreAudioTypes.h** file, both **mFormatFlag**(s) refer to the same Fixed Point 8.24 format. Clearly something is different, but I can't figure out what.

Thanks for reading through this long question, and thanks in advance for any insight you can provide.

Comment: I somehow suspect that you are experiencing distortion rather than clipping, most likely caused by sign flipping. Can you post a WAV file generated by your algorithm here so we can see what's going on?

Comment: My app plays sounds as a musical instrument. It doesn't create or store wave files. But I do think you're correct. Basically, if I knew what format *kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved* represents, I could figure out how  bit-twiddle that format in and out of SInt16. At present, all I know is its not FixedPoint 8.24

Answer (score 12):

`kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat` means that the buffer contains floating point values.  If `mBitsPerChannel` is 32 then you are dealing with `float` data (also called Float32), and if it is 64 you are dealing with `double` data.

`kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian` refers to the fact that the data in the buffer matches the endianness of the processor, so you don't have to worry about byte swapping.

`kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked` means that every bit in the data is significant.  For example, if you store 24 bit audio data in 32 bits, this flag will not be set.

`kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved` means that each individual buffer consists of one channel of data.  It is common for audio data to be interleaved, with the samples alternating between L and R channels: `LRLRLRLR`.  For DSP applications it is often easier to deinterleave the data and work on one channel at a time.

I think in your case the error is that you are treating floating point data as fixed point.  Float data is generally scaled to the interval [-1, +1).  To convert `float` to `SInt16` you need to multiply each sample by the maximum 16-bit value (`1u << 15`, 32768) and then clip to the interval [-32768, 32767].

Comment: Thanks for such an informative answer. In fact, it confirms a lot of what I've read. However, when I have tried to cast the AudioSample buffer to Float32* in my call-back, I get a warning.
    inSamplesLeft = (Float32 *) ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
    Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'AudioUnitSampleType *' (aka 'long *') from 'Float32 *' (aka Float32)

Comment: Without seeing the code it's hard to know exactly what's going on, but generally you cannot cast from a `long *` to a `float *` and expect to get correct results.

Comment: I took another stab and getting this problem solved and after re-reading your answer I made some good progress. I still have a lot of distortion but I think this may be caused by the trival method by which I'm converting Float32 to SInt16. Could you expound on the 16bit bit-shift syntax you wrote out --I'm not a C programmer yet and am unsure how to implement:  (1u << 15, 32768)

Comment: Something like this: `float sample = /* ... */; SInt16 s = (SInt16)(sample * 32768);`

Comment: Okay cool. I'm doing a straight multiplication and thought there might be a more optimized way using bit-shifting. Additionally, I discovered this morning that the noise (clipping) only happens in the 5.1 simulator. Its fine on the iPad. So that means I got a sweet echo unit working!!! Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Comment: You could probably improve performance using `Accelerate.framework`, but I haven't done any benchmarks.