# How to do a AudioUnitRender with a AudioUnitEffect?

Tags: ios, core-audio

I am trying to do a AudioUnitRender with an audioUnit Effect in the callback of a AudioUnit Mixer but no luck.

My mixer goes into a RemoteIO unit and process AudioData (from a file) in its callback. Works just fine.

I then added a AudioUnit effect node (a Reverb) to my graph and linked it to a AudioUnit. My effect node is not connected to anything in the graph.

```
AudioComponentDescription auEffectDescription;
auEffectDescription.componentType           = kAudioUnitType_Effect;
auEffectDescription.componentSubType        = kAudioUnitSubType_Reverb2;
auEffectDescription.componentManufacturer   = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
auEffectDescription.componentFlags          = 0;
auEffectDescription.componentFlagsMask      = 0;
```

I am aware about the StreamFormat issues as described in the AudioGraph (zerokidz.com/audiograph) example and have set the StreamFormat of my Effect Unit as explained in AudioGraph.

So I know there is an issue of streamformat compatibility (see [Bit-shifting audio samples from Float32 to SInt16 results in severe clipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073467/bit-shifting-audio-samples-from-float32-to-sint16-results-in-severe-clipping)). My ASBD:

```
[AudioUnitEffect]------------------------------
[AudioUnitEffect] Sample Rate:       44100
[AudioUnitEffect] Format ID:          lpcm
[AudioUnitEffect] Format Flags:         41
[AudioUnitEffect] Bytes per Packet:      4
[AudioUnitEffect] Frames per Packet:     1
[AudioUnitEffect] Bytes per Frame:       4
[AudioUnitEffect] Channels per Frame:    2
[AudioUnitEffect] Bits per Channel:     32
[AudioUnitEffect]------------------------------

[AudioUnitMixer]------------------------------
[AudioUnitMixer] Sample Rate:       44100
[AudioUnitMixer] Format ID:          lpcm
[AudioUnitMixer] Format Flags:       3116
[AudioUnitMixer] Bytes per Packet:      4
[AudioUnitMixer] Frames per Packet:     1
[AudioUnitMixer] Bytes per Frame:       4
[AudioUnitMixer] Channels per Frame:    2
[AudioUnitMixer] Bits per Channel:     32
[AudioUnitMixer]------------------------------
```

I have understood (correct me if I am wrong) that my effect is in Float32 while my Mixer uses the AudioUnitSampleType type (SInt32). I have tried various ways of converting the data buffers before and after calling the AudioUnitRender on the effect. I have tried to match the ASBD of my mixer to the AudioUnit Effect, it works but I get some horrible distortion (which would normal if the Effect uses Float32 type (between [-1,+1] I guess?).

The Apple doc says:

*Effect Units Stream format notes

On the input scope, manage stream formats as follows:
 - If the input is fed by an audio unit connection, it acquires its stream format from that connection.
 - If the input is fed by a render callback function, set your complete application stream format on the bus. Use the same stream format as used for the data provided by the callback. On the output scope, set the same full stream format that you used for the input.
*

Which I find is not that helpful..

Anyway there must a way to do a AudioRenderRender with Effect Unit. Has anyone succeded? Thanks.

André

---

My mixer callback :

```
static OSStatus mainMixerCallback(void *inRefCon, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, UInt32 inBusNumber, UInt32 inNumberFrames, AudioBufferList *ioData)
{  
SoundEngine* se = (SoundEngine*)inRefCon;

// init buffers with zeros
memset((Byte *)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData, 0, ioData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);
memset((Byte *)ioData->mBuffers[1].mData, 0, ioData->mBuffers[1].mDataByteSize);

// Render the Audio Track (works fine)
AudioUnitRender((AudioUnit)se.auTrack,ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, ioData);

//  Effect (fails when there. Error:-50)
AudioUnitRender((AudioUnit)se.auEffect, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, ioData);
    return noErr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved your problem by now, but just for the record: the buffer needs to have one channel, so you need to set up two AudioBuffers of one channel each instead of the 2 channel one you have now.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check that.